# error on "install and update" to lollipop 5.1.1 in nexus 6

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-6

I have nexus 6 with lollipop 5.0.1. There is setting to install and update to 5.1. I download and install. But facing error on half way. Showing android icon with error text. How should I do that?

Comment: What is the error text that is being displayed? Have your restarted the mobile and tried to update?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it contains "error". It restarted when update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into the same problem reported over here by fellow Nexus 4/5/7 users on the google product forum page.

[Error during updating to 5.0.1](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/nexus/svgo7hsNMMQ/2KuP1dbgF5cJ)

Some of the suggestion found there,

- Wipe cache partition
- Factory reset. (Warning! This erases all data on your phone)
- Unroot your phone if you are rooted.

But none of them seems to completely work will all other Nexus users. But you can give it a try if you are sure about each of the process. As the accepted answer posted by a Google Employee confirms that there is a bug and they are still investigating this issue,

> As several of you have noticed, a new update (still labeled 5.0.1) is
>   currently being sent to the Nexus 5 that addresses this issue. If
>   you've got a Nexus 5 but haven't received the update yet, please be
>   patient as it should be available for your device soon.
>
> Please note that we're still investigating this issue for other
>   devices (so far I've seen reports from Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 owners) but
>   I don't have further updates or a workaround to suggest at this time.
>   We appreciate your patience as we continue to look into this for other
>   devices.

Comment: thanks Lucky, I didn't fount this solution. I will try it.